# session.socket.io save session not working?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

I am using [session.socket.io](https://npmjs.org/package/session.socket.io) in my node.js application. I am using this to manage my sessions in socket functions.

```
sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {

    session.save(); //here its working

    socket.on('check_username',function(username) {  
        if(username in clients) {
            socket.emit('error', 'Username not available');
        } else {
            clients[username] = session.id;
            session.sockets.push(socket.id);
            session = { 'username': username }; 
            session.save();
            socket.emit('success', 'Welcome to chat');
        }
});
```

My problem is I can access and update session values before the `check_username` function but I can't access it with in the `check_username` function. I don't know how to resolve this...

Comment: i found the answer... i just changed the line
            session = { 'username': username }; 
to
session.username = username; then its working..

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. The below line overwrites all previous values in session variable.

```
      session = { 'username': username };
```

So then i have changed this line to below. Then its working

```
      session.username - username;
```